# In what cases should I use memcpy over standard operators in C++?

Tags: c++, performance, memory, allocation, copying

When can I get better performance using `memcpy` or how do I benefit from using it?
For example:

```
float a[3]; float b[3];
```

is code:

```
memcpy(a, b, 3*sizeof(float));
```

*faster* than this one?

```
a[0] = b[0];
a[1] = b[1];
a[2] = b[2];
```

Comment: I guess even assignment operator for float would be implemented using memcpy. So, directly using memcpy for the entire array would be faster

Comment: I don;t believe your edit. Why would the second approach be faster. memcpy() is specifically designed to copy areas of memory from one place to another so it should be as efficient as the underlying architecture will allow. I would bet that it will use appropriate assembly where applicable to do a block memory copy.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Efficiency should not be your concern.
Write clean maintainable code.

It bothers me that so many answers indicate that the memcpy() is inefficient. It is designed to be the most efficient way of copy blocks of memory (for C programs).

So I wrote the following as a test:

```
#include <algorithm>

extern float a[3];
extern float b[3];
extern void base();

int main()
{
    base();

#if defined(M1)
    a[0] = b[0];
    a[1] = b[1];
    a[2] = b[2];
#elif defined(M2)
    memcpy(a, b, 3*sizeof(float));    
#elif defined(M3)
    std::copy(&a[0], &a[3], &b[0]);
 #endif

    base();
}
```

Then to compare the code produces:

```
g++ -O3 -S xr.cpp -o s0.s
g++ -O3 -S xr.cpp -o s1.s -DM1
g++ -O3 -S xr.cpp -o s2.s -DM2
g++ -O3 -S xr.cpp -o s3.s -DM3

echo "=======" >  D
diff s0.s s1.s >> D
echo "=======" >> D
diff s0.s s2.s >> D
echo "=======" >> D
diff s0.s s3.s >> D
```

This resulted in: (comments added by hand)

```
=======   // Copy by hand
10a11,18
>   movq    _a@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rcx
>   movq    _b@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rdx
>   movl    (%rdx), %eax
>   movl    %eax, (%rcx)
>   movl    4(%rdx), %eax
>   movl    %eax, 4(%rcx)
>   movl    8(%rdx), %eax
>   movl    %eax, 8(%rcx)

=======    // memcpy()
10a11,16
>   movq    _a@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rcx
>   movq    _b@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rdx
>   movq    (%rdx), %rax
>   movq    %rax, (%rcx)
>   movl    8(%rdx), %eax
>   movl    %eax, 8(%rcx)

=======    // std::copy()
10a11,14
>   movq    _a@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rsi
>   movl    $12, %edx
>   movq    _b@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rdi
>   call    _memmove
```

Added Timing results for running the above inside a loop of `1000000000`.

```
   g++ -c -O3 -DM1 X.cpp
   g++ -O3 X.o base.o -o m1
   g++ -c -O3 -DM2 X.cpp
   g++ -O3 X.o base.o -o m2
   g++ -c -O3 -DM3 X.cpp
   g++ -O3 X.o base.o -o m3
   time ./m1

   real 0m2.486s
   user 0m2.478s
   sys  0m0.005s
   time ./m2

   real 0m1.859s
   user 0m1.853s
   sys  0m0.004s
   time ./m3

   real 0m1.858s
   user 0m1.851s
   sys  0m0.006s
```

Comment: +1. And, since you didn't write down the obvious conclusion from this, the memcpy call looks like it's generating the most efficient code.

Comment: Huh. Why isn’t the call to `_memmove` inlined?

Comment: BTW: @Martin: it is not reasonable to say "efficiency should not be your concern, write nice code". People use C++ as opposed to a decent language precisely because they demand performance. It matters.

Comment: @Yttrill: And I have never seen a micro optimization by a human that was not already being done better by compiler. On the other hand writing nice readable code implies you are thinking more at the algorithm level were the human can beat the compiler at optimization because the compiler does not know the intent.

Comment: @LokiAstari You think that 20 assign operators are easier to understand than a single memcpy on a struct? It might be more readable with memcpy too. (And in C/++ you are probably used to it anyways.)

Comment: @akaltar: I think `std::copy` is easier to read. It also the most efficient (equal to memcpy). See the supplied assembly and because you obviously did not time it yourself the timing results.

Comment: @akaltar: Also you miss the point. You **CANT** use memcopy on structures in C++ because they have constructors (there is a small subclass of structures that you can use memcopy on but that is not the general case). Which is also why `std::copy` is better as it will use the most efficient and valid technique.

Comment: @LokiAstari memcpy is usually used on data-only structs, as usually those are used in high-performance code, but I understand your point, std::copy is indeed superior. As to reading.. I think they come out equal.

Comment: Addendum: instead of C-style arrays, using `std::array<float, 3>`, which *does* have an assignment operator, combines the best of both worlds: [readability and efficiency](https://goo.gl/aUfBHF). And has the extra added quality of not decaying to a pointer, among others. Besides, as of the time of writing, both GCC 5.2 and Clang 3.7 generate identical code in all cases, so performance is no longer relevant and readability should be favored.

Comment: The C++ memmove (m3) speed looks dubious.  There's no way a call to `memmove` would have no overhead compared to the optimized and inlined `memcpy` case.

Comment: @user239558: You are surprised that `std::copy` produces the fastest code? Given the ability of the compiler to analyze and plant the best code it seems redundantly obvious that `std::copy` would be the fastest technique (or at least no slower than a technique you can do manually).

Comment: @LokiAstari the assembly was quoted in the answer above.  There is no way a non-inlined call to `memmove`, which in addition to the above needs to check for pointer overlap, could ever be as fast as the inlined `memcpy`.  It's bogus.

Comment: @user239558: Well it's a good job the compiler as a machine makes better choices based on maths than humans do with "opinions". Not only is the code provided but also the timing results. Since this is a science why don't you try and repeat the experiment!

Comment: @LokiAstari I'm just pointing out that the timings are bogus.  Anyone who has programmed in assembly or has read intel instruction manuals will know this.  It is common to make mistakes in benchmarking, and I'm simply pointing out an obvious one.  I'm not wasting any more time on this, sorry.

Comment: @user239558: Words are easy (rather than just pontificate with no proof Just try it).

Answer (score 18):

You can use `memcpy` only if the objects you're copying have no explicit constructors, so as their members (so-called POD, "Plain Old Data"). So it is OK to call `memcpy` for `float`, but it is wrong for, e.g., `std::string`.

But part of the work has already been done for you: `std::copy` from `<algorithm>` is specialized for built-in types (and possibly for every other POD-type - depends on STL implementation). So writing `std::copy(a, a + 3, b)` is as fast (after compiler optimization) as `memcpy`, but is less error-prone.

Comment: `std::copy` is properly found in `<algorithm>`; `<algorithm.h>` is strictly for backwards-compatibility.

Answer (score 12):

Compilers specifically optimize `memcpy` calls, at least clang & gcc does. So you should prefer it wherever you can.

Comment: @ismail : compilers may optimize `memcpy`, but stil it is less likely to be faster than the second approach. Please read Simone's post.

Comment: @Nawaz: I disagree. The memcpy() is likely to be faster given architecture support. Anyway this is redundant as std::copy (as described by @crazylammer) is probably the best solution.

Answer (score 6):

Use `std::copy()`. As the header file for `g++` notes:

> This inline function will boil down to a call to @c memmove whenever possible.

Probably, Visual Studio's is not much different. Go with the normal way, and optimize once you're aware of a bottle neck. In the case of a simple copy, the compiler is probably already optimizing for you.

Answer (score 5):

Don't go for premature micro-optimisations such as using memcpy like this. Using assignment is clearer and less error-prone and any decent compiler will generate suitably efficient code. If, and only if, you have profiled the code and found the assignments to be a significant bottleneck then you can consider some kind of micro-optimisation, but in general you should always write clear, robust code in the first instance.

Comment: How is assigning N (where N > 2) different array items one-by-one clearer than a single `memcpy`? `memcpy(a, b, sizeof a)` is clearer because, if the size of `a` and `b` change, you don't need to add/remove assignments.

Comment: @Chris Lutz: you have to think about the robustness of the code throughout it's lifetime, e.g. what happens if at some point someone changes the declaration of a so that it becomes a pointer instead of an array ? Assignment wouldn't break in this case, but the memcpy would.

Comment: `memcpy` wouldn't break (the `sizeof a` trick would break, but only some people use that). Neither would `std::copy`, which is demonstrably superior to both in almost every respect.

Comment: @Chris: well I would rather see a for loop than individual assignments, and of course careful use of memcpy is not off-limits for C code (I would prefer not to see it in C++ code though). But if you work on code that has a long life-cycle or if you care about such things as portability, porting to other languages or compilers, use of code analysis tools, auto-vectorization, etc, then simplicity and clarity are always more important than brevity and low level hacks.

Answer (score 4):

The benefits of memcpy? Probably readability. Otherwise, you would have to either do a number of assignments or have a for loop for copying, neither of which are as simple and clear as just doing memcpy (of course, as long as your types are simple and don't require construction/destruction).

Also, memcpy is generally relatively optimized for specific platforms, to the point that it won't be all that much slower than simple assignment, and may even be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly, as Nawaz said, the assignment version *should* be faster on most platform. That's because `memcpy()` will copy byte by byte while the second version could copy 4 bytes at a time.

As it's always the case, you should always profile applications to be sure that what you expect to be the bottleneck matches the reality.

**Edit**
Same applies to dynamic array. Since you mention C++ you should use `std::copy()` algorithm in that case.

**Edit**
This is code output for Windows XP with GCC 4.5.0, compiled with -O3 flag:

```
extern "C" void cpy(float* d, float* s, size_t n)
{
    memcpy(d, s, sizeof(float)*n);
}
```

I have done this function because OP specified dynamic arrays too.

Output assembly is the following:

```
_cpy:
LFB393:
    pushl   %ebp
LCFI0:
    movl    %esp, %ebp
LCFI1:
    pushl   %edi
LCFI2:
    pushl   %esi
LCFI3:
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax
    movl    12(%ebp), %esi
    movl    16(%ebp), %ecx
    sall    $2, %ecx
    movl    %eax, %edi
    rep movsb
    popl    %esi
LCFI4:
    popl    %edi
LCFI5:
    leave
LCFI6:
    ret
```

of course, I assume all of the experts here knows what `rep movsb` means.

This is the assignment version:

```
extern "C" void cpy2(float* d, float* s, size_t n)
{
    while (n > 0) {
        d[n] = s[n];
        n--;
    }
}
```

which yields the following code:

```
_cpy2:
LFB394:
    pushl   %ebp
LCFI7:
    movl    %esp, %ebp
LCFI8:
    pushl   %ebx
LCFI9:
    movl    8(%ebp), %ebx
    movl    12(%ebp), %ecx
    movl    16(%ebp), %eax
    testl   %eax, %eax
    je  L2
    .p2align 2,,3
L5:
    movl    (%ecx,%eax,4), %edx
    movl    %edx, (%ebx,%eax,4)
    decl    %eax
    jne L5
L2:
    popl    %ebx
LCFI10:
    leave
LCFI11:
    ret
```

Which moves 4 bytes at a time.

Comment: @Simone : the first para makes sense to me. Now I need to verify it, because I'm not sure. :-)

Comment: I don;t think memcopy copies byte by byte. It is specifically designed to copy large chunks of memory very efficiently.

Comment: Source please? Only thing that POSIX mandates is [this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/memcpy.html). BTW, see if [this implementation](http://www.gnu.org/software/mifluz/doc/doxydoc/memcpy2_8c-source.html) is that fast.

Comment: @Simone - libc writers have spend a lot of time making sure their `memcpy` implementations are efficient, and compiler writers have spent just as much time making their compilers look for cases when assignments could be made faster by `memcpy` and vice versa. Your argument of "it can be as bad as you want it to" as well as your out-of-the-blue implementation is a red herring. Look at how GCC or other compilers/libc's implement it. That'll probably be fast enough for you.

Comment: The usual rule of thumb applies: "Assume library writers aren't brain-damaged". Why would they write a `memcpy` that was only able to copy a byte at a time?

Comment: Because `memcpy` is required to be able to copy a single byte. Of course it may check if the size to copy is a multiple of 4 or 8, but with assignments you may omit the check and have faster code.

Comment: @Simone - On most modern platforms, the compiler will optimize that check. Most compilers will optimize each individual call to `memcpy` when they can.

Comment: @Chris as you can see, that's not true in every case.

Comment: @Simone : one thing : using `while` loop to do the assignments, and doing the assignment manually using constant offset is NOT same speed-wise. The latter is usually faster.

Comment: Yes, but you can't assign manually if you have a dynamically allocated array.