# What's the efficiency difference between memcpy and equal sign in C?

Tags: c, memcpy

I often use memcpy to copy a struct in C/C++.
I see someone use equal sign directly copy struct in C/C++.
For example:

```
struct A { char* name; int value; };
struct B { struct A happy[10]; }; 

struct A a1, a2;
struct B b1, b2;
memcpy(&a1, &a2, sizeof(struct A));
b1 = b2;
```

What's the efficiency difference between memcpy and equal sign ?

Comment: `=` and `memcpy` aren't equivalent in every case (in fact, they usually aren't).

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544804/in-what-cases-should-i-use-memcpy-over-standard-operators-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C != C++... let's assume C case, where you cannot overload the assignment operator.

It's worth having a look to the output of clang for your test case:

```
struct A { char* name; int value; };
struct B { struct A happy[10]; }; 

void foo() {
  struct A a1, a2;
  struct B b1, b2;
  memcpy(&a1, &a2, sizeof(struct A));
  b1 = b2;
}
```

Running the following command makes clang output the LLVM bytecode:

```
clang -S -emit-llvm foo.c -o -
```

Which outputs

```
; Function Attrs: nounwind uwtable
define void @foo() #0 {
  %a1 = alloca %struct.A, align 8
  %a2 = alloca %struct.A, align 8
  %b1 = alloca %struct.B, align 8
  %b2 = alloca %struct.B, align 8
  %1 = bitcast %struct.A* %a1 to i8*
  %2 = bitcast %struct.A* %a2 to i8*
  call void @llvm.memcpy.p0i8.p0i8.i64(i8* %1, i8* %2, i64 16, i32 8, i1 false)
  %3 = bitcast %struct.B* %b1 to i8*
  %4 = bitcast %struct.B* %b2 to i8*
  call void @llvm.memcpy.p0i8.p0i8.i64(i8* %3, i8* %4, i64 160, i32 8, i1 false)
  ret void
}
```

The interesting part is that in both case (call to `memcpy` or assign operator) a call to `@llvm.memcpy.p0i8.p0i8.i64` is generated!

Answer (score 5):

Now that the c++ tag has beed removed, we are talking C and not C++.

Assuming `a1`and `a2` being variables of the same `struct` type

```
memcpy(&a1, &a2, sizeof(struct A));
```

and

```
a1 = a2;
```

do exactly the same thing.

But it is entirely up to the compiler if the assignement operator *actually* uses `memcpy` or not.

Answer (score 4):

### C++

In C++ a structure can be plain old data (C types) or complex - requiring construction and copy constructors to be called.

the difference between memcpy and = is that = works.

When = is applied to a complex structure, it copies each of the members following their rules.
When = is applied to a simple structure (plain-old-data or POD) then it does a "memcpy".

### C

In C complex copies were not originally allowed, so some old code would memcpy over using =.  In C they equate to the same operation.